# Need assistance with reading XML data into an android application using the characters function of DefaultHandler

Tags: java, android, xml

Here is my XML code, out of which I want to read the icon tag for my android application. I am using the DefaultHandler to read the XML. I tried using the characters function but it did not work. So could you please help.

```
<Screens>
<Elements>
<Screen>ABC</Screen>
<Item id="100">
<name>addr</name>
<type>abc</type>
<icon>xyz.png</icon>
<title>Map</title>
</Item>
</Elements>
</Screens>
```

Comment: It didn't work? Why? Any issue, exception or logcat output.

Comment: I am so sorry about the vague question. Actually I just figured it out right now, shall post the answer now.

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved by using xstream. Its very simple to implement.
You just need to create a class hierarchy for above xml and you can easily access any elements from this xml file. Please read the 2 min tutorial from following: http://x-stream.github.io/tutorial.html

Answer (score 0):

```
@Override
public void startElement(String uri, String localName, String qName,
    Attributes attributes) throws SAXException {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
sb=new StringBuilder();
if(localName.equals("icon"))
{
    iconflag=true;
}
}

@Override
public void characters (char ch[], int start, int length) {
if (sb!=null && iconflag == true) {
    for (int i=start; i<start+length; i++) {
        sb.append(ch[i]);
    }
}
}

@Override
public void endElement(String uri, String localName, String qName)
    throws SAXException {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
if(iconflag)
{
    info.setIcon(sb.toString().trim());
    iconflag=false;
}
}
```

This is the solution.